# Converting string timestamp to date

Tags: java, date, format, timestamp

How do i convert a string time-stamp like **"Thu Jun 07 13:01:59 IST 2007"** to date format in **java**?

Comment: Can refer to [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Comment: I don't get it to work so easily. Tried: `new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy");`

Comment: Please show your code, and the inputs and outputs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
String ds = "Thu Jun 07 13:01:59 IST 2007";
SimpleDateFormat f = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy");
Date d = f.parse(ds);
```

As others mentioned, the answer is in the docs.

Comment: You should use `HH`, not `hh`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use DateFormat:

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("E M d HH:mm:ss z yyyy");
Date date = dateFormat.parse("Thu Jun 07 13:01:59 IST 2007");
```

Comment: -1 for using `F`. Should be `E`.

Comment: Should be `yyyy`, not `YYYY`. This will throw an exception.

Answer (score -1):

First, create a date and time pattern string as specified in the [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) javadocs and then call [`parse`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#parse%28java.lang.String%29) to convert the string to a `Date` object.

Comment: -1 not full answer. You should provide example in code

Answer (score -1):

Use `SimpleDateFormat`. Something like this:

```
DateFormat fmt = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM d hh:mm:ss Z yyyy");
Date date = fmt.parse(str);
```

Comment: You should use `HH`, not `hh`.