# How to sort array object by specific string field?

Tags: java, android

This is the class of my object (I need timestamp is a string):

```
public class Evento{
    public String timestamp;

    public Evento(String timestamp) {
        super();
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
    }
    public String getTimestamp() {
        return timestamp;
    }
}
```

In my activity I have:

```
Evento evento = new Evento[10];
for(int i = 0; i<10; i++)
    evento[i] = new Evento(/*Casual String timestamp*/);
```

Then I have populated the array, how can I sort it by the timestamp inserted?

Comment: `Arrays.sort()` and a custom implementation of the `Comparator<T>` interface

Comment: In java 8, assuming that you want a "natural" sort on the string value, you can create the comparator like: `Comparator<Evento> comparator = Comparator.comparing(Evento::getTimestamp);`  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#comparing-java.util.function.Function-

Answer (score 0):

As previously stated, you are going to need a custom implementation of the Comparator interace. Since it is a string, I would first convert the timestamp to a date object: [Converting string timestamp to date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10494876/converting-string-timestamp-to-date) , and then you could follow this example to sort by date [Sort objects in ArrayList by date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5927109/sort-objects-in-arraylist-by-date)